# Prestashop combinations tab is not loading

Tags: tabs, timeout, prestashop, combinations, prestashop-1.6

In Prestashop backend -> Product Edit -> Combination tab is not loading and throwing timeout error everytime after just 30 sec, Tried to find code from where it is getting timed out , there might be any static code for 30 secs, but did not succeed. Then checkout the AdminProductsController from where combinations tab content initiates (function initFormCombinations). Here I found that there are many numbers of combinations and most of the combinations are from the configurator module. And this thing causes request timeout.

Prestashop ver :- 1.6.1.7

Please help ?

Comment: you can increase on php max_execution time config variable

Comment: @tarekfellah I have done that already and it is around 10 minutes, also tried with set_time_limit(0) but did not worked !!

Comment: you're using a shared hosting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had configurator module and it is creating many combinations for products. So when we go to combination tab on product edit it is loading all the combinations (including custom configurator combinations), and there are so many that it was taking so many time to load.

I don't need configurator combinations on the same tab, because configurator itself gives another tab for the same. So I just discarded configurator combinations.

And it's works fine !